# Identifying the existence of hwcomposer of Project Butter in Jelly Bean

Tags: custom-roms, 4.1-jelly-bean

I've heard that some 3rd party ROMs for some devices, such as the Galaxy S3, are based on Jelly Beans. But when asked why it's not as smooth as what the makers of Jelly Bean claim they would say it's because hwcomposer, the primary component of Project Butter that makes everything smooth, is not yet there.

How do I tell if my currently installed Jelly Bean ROM has the hwcomposer? I just couldn't tell the difference in smoothness coming from ICS. I'm not saying it's laggy but I was expecting an improvement and no more occasional lags.

Comment: Did you try asking the developer whether it has it?

Comment: He said it doesn't have it. But the answer I'm looking for is how to tell so I don't have to ask every time they release their ROMs.

Answer (score 0):

On startup, check `adb logcat` for an init message that mentions the hwcomposer.

If you have a `logcat` viewer on your device (such as CatLog), you can use that, too.

Comment: hwcomposer was present in ICS upwards.